# yarn global registry location?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I've updated `yarn` to point to my custom registry and verified as below

```sh
$yarn config list -g

yarn config v1.22.10
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://npm.xxx.io/',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.10 npm/? node/v14.17.4 darwin x64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1628819793479,
  'unsafe-disable-integrity-migration': true
}
info npm config
{
  registry: 'https://npm.xxx.io/'
}
✨  Done in 0.05s.
```

As you can tell above, `registry` is pointing to `https://npm.xxx.io/`, which I then proceed to install a npm package by running command `yarn global add @my-comp/rn-cli`

And below is the error message I've got

```sh
yarn global v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@my-comp%2frn-cli: Not found".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/xxxx/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

From the error message above, it appears that `yarn` still trying to look for package from `https://registry.yarnpkg.com` which confused me. Wondering if anyone has any idea?

**UPDATES**

I've realized two thing as below:

- if I run `yarn add @my-comp/rn-cli`, package manager is able to locate the package, which means I have narrowed down the problem to "global" settings
- `yarn config get registry -g` or `yarn config get registry -gxxwhatever` both will return same result, which looks to me that yarn config actually ignored the global flag `-g`

Comment: Did you have a file name `.npmrc` to lock the source of the npm in your project ?

Comment: I do have `.npmrc` which set `registry=https://npm.xxx.io` similar to the value when I list as above @cookie

Comment: can you try `yarn --registry=https://npm.xxx.io`

Comment: @cookie: I got the below message `yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.`

Comment: @cookie: just to be clear, that message shows that nothing has changed, and i still getting 404 when installing the package

Comment: @cookie: I've updated my question to include more findings

Comment: @cookie: `npm view [package]` did returned me the result, which is expected as I can install via `yarn add @my-comp/rn-cli`. I think the problem is only on `global` level

Comment: @cookie: I've found a workaround, you can take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by manually setting `npm_config_registry`. Full command as below

```sh
npm_config_registry=https://npm.xxx.io/ yarn global add @my-comp/rn-cli
```

Found this workaround at https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5056 for others to refer

Also as pointed at https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4862 , yarn team will not support this issue as they resolved the issue in yarn v2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `yarn config set registry [npm.source] -g` to lock the npm source of your global package.